How to block stockfish and other chess engines?
Im building a chess project, where it's important that people don't cheat. Does anybody know if there is already something I can use which will detect a chess engine or do I have to make a solution on my own?

If you figure this one out, you'll be in serious business. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheating_in_chess#Incidents

Easiest way is probably to block peoples who always make the stock fish approved move

You might want to take a look at Regan's work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_W._Regan
